# Magento 2 module custom attribute not showing on layered navigation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm really quite lost here, if i create a multi-select attribute in the admin and assign values to a product and tell the attribute to show on layered navigation it works, but when i create a custom attribute in my module and do the same thing it doesn't show up on the layered navigation.

So in InstallData.php i create the attribute, which uses my own model to pull the options from a db table:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'svgs',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Select SVG/Filters',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Attributes\Options',
                'backend'=> 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Product Overview SVG/Filters',
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true
            ]
        );
```

Here is the options class, which works and shows the multi-select in admin and the values save:

```
public function getAllOptions() : array
    {

        /** @var Collection $svgCollection */
        $svgCollection = $this->svgCollectionFactory->create();

        /** @var Collection $svgCategoryCollection */
        $svgCategoryCollection = $this->svgCategoryCollectionFactory->create();

        // get all categories
        $categories = $svgCategoryCollection->setOrder('name','ASC');

        // for each category as an option group, assign SVGs
        $options = [];

        /** @var Category $category */
        foreach($categories as $category) {

            // reset where in collection so each loop works
            $svgCollection->clear()->getSelect()->reset('where');

            // get svgs in this category
            $svgs = $svgCollection->addFieldToFilter('category_id',$category->getId())
                ->setOrder('display_name','ASC');

            if($svgs->count() > 0){

                // create svgs array
                $svgOptions = [];
                /** @var SVG $svg */
                foreach ($svgs as $svg) {
                    $svgOptions[] = [
                        'label'=>$svg->getData('display_name'),
                        'value'=>$svg->getId()
                    ];
                }


                // add category with svgs to options
                $options[] = [
                    'label'=>$category->getData('name'),
                    'value'=>$svgOptions
                ];
            }
        }

       
        return $options;
    }
```

I select the options for a product and save it, but nothing is showing for the attribute in the filters on the front end.

I know i'm going to need a model for the frontend to display them properly as the attribute is saved as an array of IDs for the db table so would need to transform them on the front end to show labels, but i don't understand why it doesn't show up at all